# Show that $F(x, t) := \sin(\sum_{k=1}^n x_k - \sqrt nt)$ is a solution of $\Delta F$ $-$ $d^2F \over dt^2 $ = $0$

Tags: derivatives, wave-equation

> Given
>
> $F: \Bbb R^n$ $\mathbf x$ $\Bbb R$ $\rightarrow \Bbb R$, $n \in \Bbb N$,
>
> $(x, t) = (x_1, x_2, ..., x_n, t) \rightarrow F(x, t)$,
>
> $F(x, t) := \sin(\sum_{k=1}^n x_k - \sqrt nt)$,
>
> $\Delta F$ $:=$ $\sum_{k=1}^n$ $d^2F \over d(x_k)^2$,
>
> I would like to show that
>
> $\Delta F$ $-$ $d^2F \over dt^2 $ = $0$.

**Approach**

I take a guess that this looks much more complicated than it actually is.

First, I calculate the necessary derivatives:

$dF\over d(x_k)^2$ $= \cos(\sum_{k=1}^n x_k - \sqrt n t)$

$d^2F \over d(x_k)^2$ $= - \sin(\sum_{k=1}^n x_k - \sqrt n t)$

$dF \over dt^2$ $= \cos(\sum_{k=1}^n x_k - \sqrt n t) * (-\sqrt n)$

$d^2F \over dt^2$ $=$ $n$ $*$ $\sin(\sum_{k=1}^n x_k - \sqrt nt)  $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $sin(u)'=cos(u).u'$, $cos(u)'=-sin(u).u'$, $sin(-u)'=cos(u).(-u')$, and
$\Delta F= \sum_{i=1}^n \partial_{x_i, x_i}F$.

Comment: So, I am supposed to write the derivatives I put into the formula in a way that it becomes obvious that the term equals $0$?

Comment: Yes indeed. It is straightforward. Just do it again.

Comment: I don't quite understand. There is no term in my formula that looks like $\cos(u) * u'$.

Comment: $F(x, t) := \sin(\sum_{k=1}^n x_k - \sqrt nt)$ then what is $\partial_{x_k} F$ ? Then differentiate again with respect to $x_k$ and then take the sum over $k$.

Comment: But I've already done that - as you can see above.

Comment: Yes but it is uncorrect ! Try again with my indications.

Comment: You're right. I changed them. What do you mean by "take the sum over k"? What does this give me?

Comment: What is $\Delta F$ ? :)

Comment: $\Delta F$ $:=$ $\sum_{k=1}^n$ $d^2F \over d(x_k)^2$ by definition.

Comment: That is why you take the sum !

Comment: Yes, now I see it. So, two of the terms annulate each other. This leaves $\cos(\sum_{k=1}^n x_k - \sqrt nt)$ $*$ $-1 \over 2\sqrt{n}$

Comment: Ah, no, the derivative I calculated is still wrong.

Comment: Step by step : 1) $\partial_{x_k}F(x,t)$ 2) $\partial^2_{x_k x_k}F(x,t)$ 3) $\Delta f$ 4) $\partial^2_t F(x,t)$.

Comment: Now (!) I got it. The right derivative is $d^2F \over dt^2$ $=$ $n$ $*$ $\sin(\sum_{k=1}^n x_k - \sqrt nt)$, and $\sum_{k=1}^n  - \sin(\sum_{k=1}^n x_k - \sqrt n t)$ $=$ $n$ $*$ $-$ $\sin(\sum_{k=1}^n x_k - \sqrt n t)$. Putting these terms into the given formula, they annulate each other. Done.